# Cannot Find Application Mobilefirst

Tags: war, ibm-mobilefirst

I have deployed the war file project in context path /example
. Also i have uploaded the .wlapp and adapter in worklight console.

Where do point my application Build path to work in different server?
Should i point to /example war file path?

This is my reference on: 
http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHSCD_6.3.0/com.ibm.worklight.deploy.doc/devref/t_transporting_the_app.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To change the context root when building for a remote server, you need to right-click the application folder and select Run As > Build Setting and Remote Target.

In the window that will be displayed you need to set the remote server's server details. So those would be: protocol://host-or-ip:port/your-context-root.

Sounds like you should replace "your-context-root" with your own.

Comment: what would be  "your-context-root" ? Should it point to /example  runtime environment?where the war project file is located. OR worklight console runtime ?

Comment: The context root is the name of the project that you've created.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem. When war file project is installed it will became an runtime in IBM MobileFirst Platform Operations Console . 
So you need to choose that runtime  install .wlapp and .adapter in runtime like /example.

IBM MobileFirst Platform Operations Console
        ---->goofo(war file)
              ----->adapter
              ----->wlapp
        ---->test(war file)
              ----->adapter
              ----->wlapp